# Cannot import widget from IPython.html.widgets in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am using Jupyter to run my code.

```
from Ipython.html.widgets import interact, ButtonWidget
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
```

I am not getting the following error for that:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3fa9b991f293> in <module>()
----> 1 from IPython.html.widgets import interact, ButtonWidget
  2 from IPython.display import display, clear_output

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgets'
```

I tried to replace `IPython.html.widgets` to `ipywidgets` and execute it. It threw me back:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, ButtonWidget

ImportError: cannot import name ButtonWidget"
```

Answer (score 3):

These objects have moved with some renaming:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, Button
```